# use a class from another class which is in another file in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

i am trying to use ES6 in a project which is previously written in es5

**requirement :**

i have `class Abc` in file1.js and class `Def` in file2.js , how can i instantiate class `Abc` from `Def` in javascript ES6 and use its methods?

sample demo:
file1.js

```
class first{
constructor(a,b,c){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
}
}
```

file 2.js

```
import * as filee from  "/file1.js"
class def{
  method3(){
    let a = "satya";
    let b = "aditya";
    let c = function () {
        console.log("cr7");
    }
  let classs = new filee.first(a,b,c);
     classs.myMethod();
}
}
let a = new def();
a.method3();
```

it would be great help if anyone share good resources on ES6 , as i saw sites such as mdn but want to read articles which focus on good usage examples

Comment: You need to export something in order to import it

Comment: If you only switched from ES5 constructor functions to ES6 classes, everything should still work exactly the same. Or was your actual change to introduce ES6 modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to import something in one file you will have to export it in another file.

In your `file1.js` add the following code:

```
// vvv
export class first{
  constructor(a,b,c){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
  }
}
```

If you have multiple classes in that file, you can also export them like in the example above:

```
export class first{
  constructor(a,b,c){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
  }
}

export class second{
  constructor(a,b,c){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
  }
}
```

and then import them like this in `file2.js`:

```
import {first, second} from  "/file1.js"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an export declaration:

```
export class first { /*
^^^^^^ */
    …
}
```